# Ajax code doesn't bring me to the right page

Tags: php, ajax, authentication

I have written code, where you are supposed to be able to log in at login.html, and if you used the right information it sends you to index.php. But instead of sending me to index.php, it only shows me the popup where it says that you're logged in. I would appreciate some help, I have been stuck with this for a while.

Login.php:

```
session_start();

// connect database
[database information]

// try to connect to database
$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check for database connection error
if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
    exit('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error() . 'Neem contact op met de beheerder.');
}

// Return error when user didn't enter an email
if(!isset($_GET['email'])){
    exit('Vul een email in.');
}

// Return error when user didn't enter a password
if(!isset($_GET['password'])){
    exit('Vul een wachtwoord in.');
}

// Parse input to variables
$gebruikersemail = $_GET['email'];
$wachtwoord = $_GET['password'];

// Prepare Sql (injection prevention)
if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT userid, password, authlevel FROM user WHERE email = ?')) {
    //Bind parameters
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $gebruikersemail);
    $stmt->execute();
    //Store to check for existance
    $stmt->store_result();

    //Check if account exists
    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        //Bind result to variables
        $stmt->bind_result($idGebruiker, $gebruikerWachtwoord, $type);
        $stmt->fetch();
        //Account exists check for password
        if (password_verify($wachtwoord, $gebruikerWachtwoord)) {
            //Valid password
            //Regen session
            session_regenerate_id(true);
            //Set session values for later use
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $gebruikersemail;
            $_SESSION['id'] = $idGebruiker;
            $_SESSION['type'] = $type;
            //Send user to main page
            echo 'loggedin';
        }
        else {
            echo 'Het ingevoerde wachtwoord is incorrect.';
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'Het ingevoerde email is niet bij ons bekend.';
    }

    //Close database connection
    $stmt->close();

}
```

Login.js (Someone gave this to me to make ajax easier (i think))

```
function auth() {
    email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
    sendGetRequest("login.php", {email: email, password: pass}, function callback(r) {
        if (r == "loggedin") {
            location.href = 'index.php';
        } else {
            alert(r);
        }
    });
}
```

Index.php

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    header('Location: login.html');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Show the code of sendGetRequest please

Comment: I am not sure what's meant with 'show the code of sendGetRequest' to be honest. Literally all code I have is here, except login.html which is just some html with inputs and a login button.

Comment: The function `sendGetRequest` is not shown here so nobody knows what it does or does not do. If you do not have that function defined in your code you should be getting errors ( check the console ) to confirm that. As it is the above ajax code is not ajax... Also would be nice to see where/how you are calling the `auth` function

Comment: This is literally all I have, I have the auth connected to my login button. I am not getting any errors.

Comment: Can you observe any XHR traffic in the console when you press the button?

Comment: I honestly have no idea what XHR traffic is. I can see the console. When I log in nothing happens in the console.

Comment: It means open the Network tool (next to the Console), and then run the code, and see if you see any request going to your login.php script. P.s. (xhr is another name for Ajax)

Comment: `XHR` - XML Http Request ... ie: AJAX. There will be a tab in the console for `network` and you should be able to filter this to just XHR traffic. If there is no request then you are not going to have any luck with the login.

Comment: Yeah, there is a request.
```
GET
 http://localhost/php%20eindopdracht%202/login.php?email=test@test.nl&password=test
```

Comment: `This is literally all I have`...there **must** be a function defined somewhere in your JavaScript called sendGetRequest - either within your page or within a.js file that your page is referencing. If there wasn't, you would get a console error the second you run it. So either a) you're wrong that you don't have this code, b) in you're not looking for console errors properly after you've executed the code) or c) not even the auth() function is executing - you can use the debugger or some console.log commands to verify that.

Comment: Ok good there is a request. Now click onto it to open it up, and see what it returns - what was the http status code, and what exactly is in the Response area?

Comment: The status says '200 OK'. I'm not sure what the response area is, but if I click on the button called 'Answer' (Or something like that, mine isn't on English) it shows HTML loggedin, which most likely is the popup.

Comment: The `response area` is what you can see when you click on the request in the console. It will reveal many things about the request (headers,data,timings) - if the request is working and the PHP code running correctly you should expect to either see `loggedin` or `Het ingevoerde email is niet bij ons bekend.`

Comment: Then it shows 'loggedin'.

Comment: If it shows `loggedin` it suggests that all is OK ( btw: In previous comment there is another possible piece of text that might be displayed if the password is wrong. ) so... in the AJAX callback where you test `if(r=='loggedin'` etc put an alert or console.info to show what the response is

Comment: Added a console log here:  
``` if (r == "loggedin") {
            location.href = 'index.php';
            console.log('test');```

It did not show anything in the console :/

Comment: before the logic test... you do not necessarily know that the response is `loggedin` and log the actual response not `test`

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with that, to be honest.

Comment: is it possible that the response is not simply `loggedin` - could there be any other characters such as spaces at the start/end? We have no way to test your code so we rely upon you doing reasonable debugging. You know the login code in PHP works so you need to deduce what is going on within the callback and determine why the logic test does not redirect you to `index.php`... however in `index.php` have you enabled the session using `session_start()`?

Comment: I think if I'm right, there is a space after 'loggedin' for some reason in the response. I'm not sure why it's there.

In index.php I don't have a session_start(), do I need to add that?

Comment: `if( r.trim() == 'loggedin' ){...etc }`

Comment: Wow. That worked. Thank you so much, it sends me to index.php now! :D

Comment: `In index.php I don't have a session_start(), do I need to add that? `...well you will if you want it to be able to check the session to see if the person is actually logged in or not (because obviously you don't want them going straight to index.php without going via the login page, do you)

Comment: You have a closing tag at the end probably `?>`. Remove it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question was to add trim.

```
function auth() {
    email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
    sendGetRequest("login.php", {email: email, password: pass}, function callback(r) {
        if (r.trim() == "loggedin") {
            location.href = 'index.php';
        } else {
            alert(r);
        }
    });
}
```